# Port 4444 is busy, please choose a free port and specify it using -port option

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

i install protractor using this command:

> npm install -g protractor,
>
> webdriver-manager update,
>
> webdriver-manager start,

after installing this webdriver manager was running fine. then for some reason i thought i need selenium server standalone. so i install it using this command:

> npm install selenium-standalone@latest -g selenium-standalone install
>   selenium-standalone start

Now if I run any one of either webdriver-manager start or selenium -standalone start I get these error. I am not running both at the same time.

```
I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.41 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.21.0 -jar /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -port 4444
[10:17:56] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 39645
10:17:57.250 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292'
10:17:57.251 INFO [GridLauncherV3$1.launch] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2018-08-02 10:17:57.408:INFO::main: Logging initialized @612ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
10:17:57.589 ERROR [SeleniumServer.boot] - Port 4444 is busy, please choose a free port and specify it using -port option
[10:17:57] I/start - Selenium Standalone has exited with code 0.
```

if anyone knows the reason please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

try the following to kill anything on that port:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -ti tcp:4444)
```

If the command  **webriver-manager** **shutdown** does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Because a selenium server started by `webdriver-manager start` on the default port 4444, and it's still running, not terminal.

So when you execute `webdriver-manager start` or `selenium -standalone start` without specifying port, it will try to start another selenium server on 4444 again which is used by previous selenium server. That's why you get `Port 4444 is busy`

You can find the process of selenium server and kill it to release the port 4444, or specify the port to different number for `webdriver-manager start` or `selenium -standalone start`

Try `webdriver-manager shutdown` to stop selenium server.

And `webdriver-manager update` will install selenium-server-standalone.jar, so you no need to install `selenium-standalone` to help to install selenium-server-standalone.jar.

Comment: thanks for help yong. webdriver-manager shutdown shuts the server but it doesnt solve this . it getting same issue. do you know how to uninstall selenium-server standalone?

Comment: You cann execute `npm uuninstall -g selenium-standalone` or delelte the `selenium-standalone` folder from `<npm global package install folder>\node_modules`.  For your issue still existing,  please check another other program run on 4444 already.

Answer (score 2):

You can type in your console(cmd for Windows)

> webdriver-manager

and it will give you a list of options for your Selenium Standalone server. If you want to change the port use --seleniumPort option,

> webdriver-manager start --seleniumPort 12345

this will change your port to 12345, so Selenium Server would start on port 12345, instead of 4444.

Hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

just start selenium standalone server at another port : 
e.g :

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\Essentials\SeleniumStandaloneJars>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -port 8090
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue when running protractor tests.
The below two solutions works for me

1) Stop server by below command.
    http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer

2) Uncomment seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub 
    save and run the tests.

```
In case-2: Selenium web driver starts running by default on start running the protractor tests.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below command to start the server by changing the Port Number

> java -
>   Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\chromedriver_path\chromedriver_2.45.exe
>   -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Users\geckodriver_path\geckodriver-v0.23.0.exe
>   -jar C:\Users\selenium_server_jar_path\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
>   -port 4446

Please change the paths as per your system configurations
[This Solution is for Windows machine]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows:

As you are using npm, an easy solution is to install

`$ npm install --global kill-port`
and then you can call

`$ kill-port --port 4444`

before running your tests.

If you are on Mac or Linux: you can use `pkill -f selenium-standalone`

Answer (score 1):

if you are following Megan Lewis course on LinkedIn you should specify your own port

```
java -jar .\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub -port 5555 (choose your number)
```